# Switch button for dark mode

Tags: laravel

I'm following a little advice / tutorial from a forum to create a button (a select) that switches the theme modes (light, dark). This is the following code, which unfortunately I can't get to work, yet everything looks ok.

```
<body class="font-sans antialiased {{ session('theme', 'theme-light') }}">
```

```
<form action="{{ route('themes.update') }}" method="PUT">
   @csrf
   @method('PUT')
   <select name="theme">
      <option value="darkly">Dark</option>
      <option value="cerulean">Light</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

and routes

```
Route::put('/themes', function(Request $request) {
   $request->validate([
      'theme' => ['required', Rule::in(['darkly', 'cerulean'])]
   ]);

   session(['theme' => $request->theme]);
   return back();
})->name('themes.update');
```

Then selecting the various items in the select, nothing happens, how could I solve? I also wanted to implement a switch button later.

Comment: You need to submit your form. This can either be done with a submit button or using JavaScript an a change event listener.

Comment: Could you give me some examples? I'm not very familiar with javascript

Answer (score 1):

the method "PUT" which is specified in the form is not valid.
Possible (case insensitive) values:

- method="get" (data transmission via URL variables)
- method="post" (data transmission cia HTTP post transaction / request body)

However, so that you can still address a PUT route even though the HTML specification says you can't, you can add a hidden _method field to fake these HTTP verbs in Laravel. The @method blade directive can create this field for you:

```html
<form action="{{ route('themes.update') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    <select name="theme">
        <option value="darkly">Dark</option>
        <option value="cerulean">Light</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```